# Capturing repeating number groups with regex in java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have one or more telephone numbers in a string. They are separated with spaces. How can i capture those numbers into groups, without spaces? And I dont want to use split.

Comment: Example please.? or may be try `string.split(" ");`.

Comment: What's the format of the telephone number?

Comment: for example String numbers="2398989 1289813 9823981   1989213   "

Comment: *"I dont want to use split."*  Why should we care what you want?  It is what works (and forms logical, readable code), that is the important thing.

Comment: So, you just want a string.split(" "); reimplemented as a regex?

Comment: Yes, Im intrested how can I do split in regex

Comment: @jyriand : [`string.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes regex as an argument

Comment: Im using: Pattern and Matcher, thats why i need regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you're looking something to split anything by spaces. This is the regex I'd use:

```
([^ ]+)
```

Probably, using this would be a better choice:

```
([^\s]+)
```

Because this would include any whitespace characters (space, tab, NL, FF, VT, CR).

However, I agree with the rest of the commenters that going for a split() is your best choice...

Here is the [regex example](http://rubular.com/r/ZIITaPB2gS).

Answer (score 2):

Try `String.split()` method.

```
String []numbers=string.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use regex and all the phone numbers are digits(no other chars).

Try this code:

```
    String phone = "11111 22222 33333 44444";
    String regex = "(\\d+)";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(phone);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

Comment: Will it make a group for each separate telephone number?

Comment: No. You should get each matched telephone number in each step of the while loop. They are not stored in an array or something at the first match.  You can take the find() as the meaning of findNext.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a regex. You can try

```
String phoneNumbers = "2398989 1289813 9823981 1989213";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{7})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumbers);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

By the way string.split also take a regex.